# Do shell functions and aliases fork child processes?

Tags: bash, shell, process, alias, function

Do shell functions and aliases fork child processes?  Or are they both executed within the shell process?

Answer (score 4):

No.

An alias is a simple substitution of one (or more) words for some string before the line is parsed to tokens. There is no shell context change needed.

From bash manual on [Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions):

> Shell functions are executed in the current shell context; no new process is created to interpret them.

Unless the code that compose the function does fork a subprocess, like in bash with `(…)` (not in ksh). A function could be defined with parenthesis instead of (or additionally to) curly braces.

Test:

```
#!/bin/bash
func(){ echo "$BASHPID"; }
fork()( echo "$BASHPID"; )
echo "$BASHPID"
func
fork
```

On execution:

```
$ ./script
8731
8731
8753
```

Understand the fork function as:

```
fork(){
        ( echo "BASHPID" )
      }
```

Comment: Or more to the point, a function is just giving a name to a command (though in `bash` contrary to most other Bourne-like shells), it's limited to _compound_ commands (including, but not limited to `(...)` and `{...;}`). Invoking the function is like invoking the corresponding compound command (with the added benefits that you can pass arguments that will be available as `$1`, `$2`... in the command and with some shells have local scope for variables or options inside). So if the command forks a subshell, that will fork a subshell and if not, not.

Comment: Note that _subshell_ and _forking a child process_ are not necessarily the same thing. Most shells (including `bash`) implement subshells by forking, but they don't have to. ksh93 for instance doesn't.